# migration from EF core 2.2 to 3.0 with SQL breaking change

Tags: ef-core-2.2, ef-core-3.1

Migrating from dotnetcore 2.2 to 3.1 is creating many linq queries to break because of the client evaluation removed breaking change.

Is there a way to find out which queries are evaluated on client side before proceeding to the migration ? to avoid the strategy of migrating first then fix one by one all queries that are failing.

Comment: This means the queries were *already buggy* and now break. EF Core 2.2 [was already logging warnings for those queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#previous-versions). You can [configure EF Core 2.x logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v2) to see what's going on already, or throw immediatelly with `ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning))`

Comment: As for what's evaluated on the client, anything that's too complicated or uses any kind of client-side function should be investigated. String operations, "clever" groupings, queries with big joins instead of relations. Anywhere where LINQ was used as a SQL replacement instead of a language for querying on top of entities with their relations. .NET string parsing, date/number formatting can't be translated to SQL either. Casts or calls to Convert. Calls to `ToLower()` or `ToUpper()` are translated but just harm performance - databases typically use case -*in*sensitive collation

Comment: ok that is a satisfying answer. I have activated that and am understanding what I was doing wrong and causing client side evaluation. I am surprised ReSharper is not able to identify those